# :target class repeats previous animation

Tags: html, css

Could some give me hand with this animation the problem I'm having is with the target class which is on the close button of my messages - line 161 of my [codepen.io](http://codepen.io/kirkdm/pen/EjYzzb). The problem I'm having is making the display:block to display none and not re-show the element again - when you click the cross button it disappears but when you click another cross button on another message it show the previous one again - how can this be stopped, could someone give me some help please.

[codepen.io](http://codepen.io/kirkdm/pen/EjYzzb)

```
.wrapper:target{    
  -webkit-animation: close_toast 2s ease both;
  -moz-animation: close_toast 2s ease both;
  animation: close_toast 2s ease both;  
}

@-webkit-keyframes close_toast {
  0% { 
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
    right: 0px;
  } 
  99% {
    opacity: 0;
    right: 0px;     
  }
  100% {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;    
    right: 0px;    
  }
}
```

Comment: You can't animate display

Comment: what can you do to compensate for that

Comment: Try the `opacity` or `height` property, depending on the effect you're looking for. Make sure to culminate with `display:none`.

Answer (score 0):

animation is not available for display. opacity animation is enough to make it appear and disappear so you can remove display:none and try again